# How do I merge 2 txt file of different layout into a single file using linux command?

Tags: sql, unix

I have 2 txt files.
File 1: columns are A,B,C,F
file 2: Columns are A,B,D,E
Final file should have following columns : A,B,C,D,E,F
How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script with the following steps:
first sort the files
`sort file1 -o file1sorted`
`sort file2 -o file2sorted`

use the `paste` command to combine
`paste file1sorted file2sorted > combofile`

use `awk` to rearrange the columns
`awk -F' ' '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$4}' combofile > finalfile`

The -F is field separator and I have assumed it to be space; if it is a comma you write it as -F,
Each value $1, $2, etc are the order of the fields in the combofile.